# Calculating multiple fields using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator

I have found a script that can add multiple fields to my existing shapefefile. Now, I need to add to my existing script so that it will calculate the new fields that have been added. In most cases, these calculations will derive from existing values in other fields ex. Crdrt1 = [Field1], Crdrt_min1 = [Field2]. I know that I need to use "fields.arcpy.CalculateField_management" but not sure how or where to add to existing script to get it to loop through and calculate.

```
import arcpy

#Select Geodatabase
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:.. FOLDER\CASINGS_DATA\casings.gdb"
#Select FeatureClass
shapefile = "Casings"

#List of fields to add, all with same type, precision, and scale
#Fields added to attribute table in reverse order
fields = {
    "Crdrt1": "[DES]",
    "Crdrt_min1": "[GRADE]",
    "Testing": "[NAME]"
}
alias = {
    "Crdrt1": "ok",
    "Crdrt_min1": "test"
}

existing_fields = arcpy.Describe(shapefile).fields


for field in fields:
    if not field in existing_fields:
        arcpy.AddField_management(shapefile, field, "TEXT", 0, 0, 50, alias [aliass])
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(shapefile, field, fields[field])
```

Comment: ArcGIS Pro has [Calculate Fields](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/calculate-fields.htm) (note the plural)

Comment: You can use the da.UpdateCursor instead of Field Calculator

Comment: Could you please provide an example of the type of calculations you would like to do?

Comment: Calculations will be simply populating based off of other columns as described in initial post. Created_Field_1 = [Existing_Field_1], Created_Field_2 = [Existing_Field_2]

Comment: I noticed that your for/if blocks might mix tab and spaces. you should avoid this and it might have confused the python 2.7 interpreter (you get an error in modern pythons when you mix tabs and spaces)

Comment: @Paul H It runs fine but populates all new added field alias as "ok". I need it to populate alias based on each value in script.

Answer (score 4):

You need to call CalculateField_management for each field you want to calculate. E.g.

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management(shapefile, "Crdrt1", "[Field1]")
arcpy.CalculateField_management(shapefile, "Crdrt_min1", "[Field2]")
```

If you want to use a loop, you could create a dictionary that contains the fieldnames and the expressions for each field. The syntax of the expression depends on the type of database and the expression type. See [here](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/calculate-field.htm) for details.

```
fields = {
    "Crdrt1": "[Field1]",
    "Crdrt_min1": "[Field2]"
}

existing_fields = arcpy.Describe(shapefile).fields

for field in fields:
    if not field in existing_fields:
        arcpy.AddField_management(shapefile, field, "TEXT", 0, 0, 250)
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(shapefile, field, fields[field])
```

Comment: Only thing that may be an issue is that I need this to potentially overwrite existing data. its throwing back an error that the field already exist if i try running twice. Anyway to avoid that or will i need to delete the fields before each run?

Comment: Nice, clean approach +1. For comparison, and to satisfy my curiosity, I included a benchmark test using your approach and an Update Cursor approach.

Comment: @huskersila I added a check for existing fields. The data in those fields will still be overwritten of course.

Comment: @Berend Thank you for your help! Much appreciated friend

Comment: @Berend What about taking this a step further and adding a field alias ? I would prefer the fields display without the "_" between field names. Adding an alias would resolve this.

Comment: @huskersila Sure, why not? `AddField_management()` has a parameter for the alias.

Comment: @Berend  I displayed updated code at top of page. Its populating "ok" as the alias for all new fields added. I need it to assign specific alias names to each specified field. I know my code is close. What am I missing?

Comment: Please don't make substantial edits to your question after it has been answered. You're breaking the Q/A format of this site.

Comment: You should use `alias[field]`

Comment: @Berend ..apologies regarding the site format...... i attempted to type code in this box and it was too long and wouldnt allow me to. That was the only place I saw where I could post code. My code is accomplishing all task that I set out to achieve. I can add a filed, calculate the field and now assign the field alias. Thank you for all of your help!

Comment: @Berend .... Do you know what determines the order of the fields when added to the attribute table ? I changed the order multiple times in script but its adding them in random order.

Answer (score 3):

In your case, using an [UpdateCursor](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/data-access/updatecursor-class.htm) is much more efficient than the [Field Calculator](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/calculate-field.htm) approach (see benchmark results below). The example I include uses a shapefile with three fields and 500,000 rows. I have included code to handle existing fields as per your comments.

```
import arcpy, time

shp = r'X:\temp\some_shapefile1.shp'
shp2 = r'X:\temp\some_shapefile2.shp'

# Dictionary of existing and created field names for Update Cursor
dict = {
    "created1": "existing1",
    "created2": "existing2",
    "created3": "existing3",
}

dict2 = {
    "created1": "[existing1]",
    "created2": "[existing2]",
    "created3": "[existing3]",
}

def add_fields(in_table, fields):
    """
    Add fields from dictionary if they do not already exist
    """
    field_names = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(in_table)]
    for field in fields:
        if not field in field_names:
            arcpy.AddField_management(in_table, field, field_type = "TEXT", field_precision = 250)

def calc_update_cursor(shp, dict):
    """
    Copy values from existing to created in dictionary
    """
    for key, value in dict.items():
        with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(shp, (key, value)) as cursor:
            for row in cursor:
                row[0] = row[1]
                cursor.updateRow(row)

def calc_field_calculator(shp2, dict2):
    for field in dict2:
        arcpy.CalculateField_management(shp2, field, dict2[field])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Speed test for update cursor
    start = time.time()
    add_fields(shp, dict.keys())
    calc_update_cursor(shp, dict)
    end = time.time()
    total = end - start
    print "%s seconds for the update cursor method" % total

    # Speed test for field calculator
    start = time.time()
    add_fields(shp2, dict.keys())
    calc_field_calculator(shp2, dict2)
    end = time.time()
    total = end - start
    print "%s seconds for the field calculator method" % total
```

---

```
*** Python 2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 20:19:30) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32. ***
>>> 
87.7679998875 seconds for the update cursor method
263.031000137 seconds for the field calculator method
>>> 
40.0729999542 seconds for the update cursor method
213.185000181 seconds for the field calculator method
>>> 
38.8159999847 seconds for the update cursor method
218.700000048 seconds for the field calculator method
>>>
```